# DC to DC converter: How do I convert 110 Vdc to 5 Vdc with 2.5 Amps current?

Tags: voltage, dc-dc-converter, buck, circuit-design

I am new in circuit designing and want to design a circuit for a DC to DC converter.  Input voltage is \$V_i\$=110 VDC ,wheras output dc volatage is \$V_o\$=5 V with \$I_o\$=2.5 Amps current . So can anybody tell me how can I do it?

Comment: I could suggest Dc> oscillator>Transformer> Bridge rectifying> smoothing>buck voltage regulator> more smoothing> Output

Comment: @Bradman175 The OP is talking about a DC to DC converter, there is no mention of AC.

Comment: @HandyHowie Looks like I read it too quickly. Changed my comment.

Comment: Go look up **switch-mode power supply**, and study how they work and how they are constructed. By the way, when you're new to electronics, you really shouldn't be playing with 110 VDC.

Comment: 110V is quite lethal. You are newbie so it is not good idea to learn and play around with 110V. You are newbie, you will make mistakes for sure. And mistakes here could hurt.

Comment: You're looking for a buck converter. But most buck ICs won't tolerate 110V so you'll need to find one that can control an extra HV transistor. And you'll need a separate LV supply to start it up, so it's not a trivial design job. Probably you want to buy a ready made solution.

Comment: If this is at a hobbyist level, just buy a plug-in USB charger and cut up a spare USB cord.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution is to buy it online.

But if you want to learn how to make it for $8 plus board and h/w costs
login to TI.com (free) use the webench designer. choose 100Vin 5V 2.5Aout and in seconds you can choose the best design, With BOM board layout, costs and simulation in seconds.

I did it and exported the Eagle library.[zip file here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2YQXhZBm9vkY1pnWk8xaV94NGs)

If you choose MOSFET for suffient voltage a drop >15V to the chip with a Zener it will then work for 115Vdc in

IN Webench, you choose then [open design] for this.

[image]

Read [**datasheet** for design details.](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm5116.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

For that kind of step-down ratio (110:5) you need a flyback or other coupled inductor based SMPS topology. This is not the simplest of topologies especially as it involves the transformer. This kind of flyback is of course very common so you can find one off the shelf.

As others have pointed out, 110VDC is no laughing matter. It's considered safe for "instructed people" according to IEC 62368 classification (ES2) but it's not harmless and that kind of voltage can have bad consequences (fire, electrical burns) otherwise as well.

Where are you getting 110VDC from btw? If you have a rectifier for 110VAC it's actually 155VDC, even worse.

I wouldn't suggest this as the first electronics project unless you've got a supervisor.

Comment: I want to use this converter for Railway signalling

Comment: @sagar Somehow I don't think that's going to be for a commercial train network?

Comment: @sagar You also need a way to supply the operating voltage for a SMPS controller, usually for off-line application you'd have an auxiliary winding in the flyback transformer but that won't work since you've got DC input. Simple resistor + zener combination would work but watch out for power dissipation. Some high-voltage linear regulators exist as well but you'd have to watch the power dissipation there as well.